# Working with distance_of_time_in_words in Rails 3

Tags: time

I am trying to make use of Rail's `distance_of_time_in_words` helper but I'm getting an Undefined Method Error for some reason. Here's my code:

```
def confirm_has_quota
  last_upload = current_user.photos.last.created_at
  remaining_time = distance_of_time_in_words(1.day.ago, last_upload)
  if last_upload < 1.day.ago
    return true
  else
    flash[:error] = "You are allowed 1 upload per day. Please try again in" + remaining_time + "."
    redirect_to(:back)
  end
end
```

Which gives me "undefined method `distance_of_time_in_words'". Anyone see what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The distance_of_time_in_words method is an ActionView Helper, thus needs to be called from the View (not the controller).

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html

Answer (score 5):

Or you can access the same through the view_context which is available inside the controllers.

```
view_context.distance_of_time_in_words
```